# Error when using a declared variable return function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I'm trying to create a function that creates a variable percent increase and then use this value to produce a forecast for a month in the coming year.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getPredictedSales(forecastmonth int(2))
RETURNS DOUBLE(6,2)
BEGIN
SELECT @percentincrease = (SELECT (SUM(s19.totalsales) / SUM(s18.totalsales))
FROM Sales2018 s18
INNER JOIN Sales2019 s19 ON s18.month = s19.month AND s18.shopname = s19.shopname
WHERE s18.month = forecastmonth)

RETURN (SELECT (SUM(s19.totalsales)*(@percentincrease)) FROM Sales2019 s19 WHERE month = 1));

END
```

Here is the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN (SELECT (SUM(s19.totalsales)*(@percentincrease)) FROM Sales2019 s19 WHERE' at line 9
```

Comment: Haven't you already learned about terminating semicolons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59229575/creating-a-function-for-predicted-sales#59229575)?

Comment: @stickybit sorry I don't understand could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put in a semicolon at the end of every statement.
And you have a bracket to much by the return.

So it should look so.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getPredictedSales(forecastmonth int(2))
RETURNS DOUBLE(6,2)
BEGIN
  SELECT @percentincrease = (SELECT (SUM(s19.totalsales) / SUM(s18.totalsales))
  FROM Sales2018 s18
  INNER JOIN Sales2019 s19 ON s18.month = s19.month AND s18.shopname = s19.shopname
  WHERE s18.month = forecastmonth);

  RETURN (SELECT (SUM(s19.totalsales)*(@percentincrease)) FROM Sales2019 s19 WHERE month = 1);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```